# Web Service Java

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola, intento consumir los servicios web de java, pero a la hora de meter el usuario y el password me indica que no es valido cuando esos datos los tengo en mi base de datos.

este es mi codigo, pero no le veo ningun error, si pudieran ayudarme con este detalle se los agradeceria.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.